# GenoTechs GTSizer component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Does anyone know of a 3rd party component that works like GTSizer? It appears that GenoTechs no longer exists. We have a number of forms in our Delphi/Oracle enterprise application that have the GTSizer component. We have Delphi 2009 to install but GTSizer is not compatible, so we are holding off for now. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what GTSizer does/did?

Comment: Automatic resolution independence between 640x480 and 1280x1024.  
  
Ensures that your forms appear virtually the same size at run time regardless of the run time resolution.

Allows the user to resize the width and height simultaneously, while keeping labels close to their edit fields.

More at http://www.genotechs.com/gtsizer.html. Website exists but email and phone numbers don't.

Some of these issues are handled better in recent versions of Delphi, but we have unchanged legacy code from Delphi 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this one;

```
procedure ScaleForm(F: TForm; ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight: LongInt) ;
begin
   F.Scaled := True;
   F.AutoScroll := False;
   F.Position := poScreenCenter;
   F.Font.Name := 'Arial';
   if (Screen.Width <> ScreenWidth) then begin
     F.Height :=
         LongInt(F.Height) * LongInt(Screen.Height)
         div ScreenHeight;
     F.Width :=
         LongInt(F.Width) * LongInt(Screen.Width)
         div ScreenWidth;
     F.ScaleBy(Screen.Width,ScreenWidth) ;
   end;
end;
```

Source: About.com, zarko gajic

Comment: Link to referenced article: http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/a/aa030700a.htm

Answer (score 1):

I use anchors and alignment to handle grids, memos, etc, like [GenoTechs](http://www.genotechs.com/gtsizer.html) shows in their [animated example](http://www.genotechs.com/gtscreen.gif).

I've never been a fan of changing the size of button and edit controls and their fonts based on resizing the window.  [GTSizer demo](http://www.genotechs.com/d5demoapps.zip).

Comment: I Agree with you Bruce, I do the same too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [DevEx's Layout Control](http://www.devexpress.com/products/VCL/ExLayoutControl/) does what you need. OTOH, it might be major overkill. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [elastic forms](http://www.elasticform.com/), but they haven't updated it for D2009 and I haven't tested it on D2009 yet.